# Repeated measures - predictor varies but outcome doesn't

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model

I have been asked to help analyse some data for a research project. The outcome is binary (presence or absence of a particular disease) and the predictor of interest is a cell count. So logistic regression will be a starting point. I was going to try using lme4::glmer but realise on talking to the researcher that disease status doesn't change for these patients. They always either have the disease or don't.

It doesn't make sense to use mixed models in this case right, as there's no within-cluster variation in the outcome? But then what about the multiple measures of the predictor that do vary? Is a reasonable solution to simply average these values per patient and then treat each summary 'observation' as independent and use standard models?

Is there any other way to make use of the repeated measures themselves rather than calculating summary stats?

Thanks